# One HTTP request, two responses?

Tags: networking, http, wireshark

I'm experimenting with my Samsung wireless speaker. I've been using Wireshark to examine and reverse engineer its API. One of the API calls I make causes strange behaviour where it seems one HTTP request returns two HTTP responses.

```
curl -v http://192.168.1.165:55001/UIC\?cmd\=%3Cname%3EGetMainInfo%3C/name%3E
```

[image: Wireshark capture for the above command]

What's frustrating, is that it's the second response that has the payload I'm after. How can I get to it?

**Curl output**

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.165...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.165 (192.168.1.165) port 55001 (#0)
> GET /UIC?cmd=%3Cname%3EGetMainInfo%3C/name%3E HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.165:55001
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 02 Jan 1970 09:31:25 GMT
< Server: Samsung/1.0
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 215
< Connection: close
< Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Jan 1970 09:31:25 GMT
< 
* Closing connection 0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UIC><method>RequestDeviceInfo</method><version>1.0</version><speakerip>192.168.1.165</speakerip><user_identifier>public</user_identifier><response result="ok"></response></UIC>
```

**Wireshark HTTP response 1/2**

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UIC><method>RequestDeviceInfo</method><version>1.0</version><speakerip>192.168.1.165</speakerip><user_identifier>public</user_identifier><response result="ok"></response></UIC>`

**Wireshark HTTP response 2/2**

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UIC><method>MainInfo</method><version>1.0</version><speakerip>192.168.1.165</speakerip><user_identifier></user_identifier><response result="ok"><party>off</party><partymain></partymain><grouptype>N</grouptype><groupmainip>0.0.0.0</groupmainip><groupmainmacaddr>00:00:00:00:00:00</groupmainmacaddr><spkmacaddr>xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx</spkmacaddr><spkmodelname>SPK-WAM3500</spkmodelname><groupmode>none</groupmode><channeltype>invalid</channeltype><channelvolume>0</channelvolume><multichinfo>on</multichinfo><groupspknum>1</groupspknum><dfsstatus>dfsoff</dfsstatus><protocolver>2.3</protocolver><btmacaddr>xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx</btmacaddr></response></UIC>`

**netcat**

Netcat did the job it seems:

```
$ nc 192.168.1.165 55001
GET /UIC?cmd=%3Cname%3EGetMainInfo%3C/name%3E HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.165

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Jan 1970 10:53:13 GMT
Server: Samsung/1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 215
Connection: close
Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Jan 1970 10:53:13 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UIC><method>RequestDeviceInfo</method><version>1.0</version><speakerip>192.168.1.165</speakerip><user_identifier>public</user_identifier><response result="ok"></response></UIC>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Jan 1970 10:53:13 GMT
Server: Samsung/1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 684
Connection: close
Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Jan 1970 10:53:13 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UIC><method>MainInfo</method><version>1.0</version><speakerip>192.168.1.165</speakerip><user_identifier></user_identifier><response result="ok"><party>off</party><partymain></partymain><grouptype>N</grouptype><groupmainip>0.0.0.0</groupmainip><groupmainmacaddr>00:00:00:00:00:00</groupmainmacaddr><spkmacaddr>xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx</spkmacaddr><spkmodelname>SPK-WAM3500</spkmodelname><groupmode>none</groupmode><channeltype>invalid</channeltype><channelvolume>0</channelvolume><multichinfo>on</multichinfo><groupspknum>1</groupspknum><dfsstatus>dfsoff</dfsstatus><protocolver>2.3</protocolver><btmacaddr>xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx</btmacaddr></response></UIC>
```

Comment: You can get an HTTP response in multiple packets. What is the output of your curl request?

Comment: @Biswapriyo added both payloads, thanks for looking

Comment: What happens if you `echo 'GET /UIC?cmd=%3Cname%3EGetMainInfo%3C/name%3E HTTP/1.1' | socat - TCP:192.168.1.165:55001` (or variants with more headers, or `telnet` if you don't have `socat`)? The point is to avoid `curl` reacting on the wrong length in the first response together with `Connection: close`.

Comment: @dirkt I used netcat, which seemed to do the job

Comment: So you have the answer: The speaker API is buggy; the headers specify only the first reply, and every client that'll try to use this API will run into that problem.